# Bounty page does not load page 1 when click on bounties

Tags: bug, bounty, new-nav, pagination

When click on bounties it loads the page number that has been selected previously, instead it should load the first page of bounty page.

To reproduce this, Select python tag and go to 5th page of that.
Then click on the bounties tab on top (refer screenshot).

It tries to load page 5 of bounties and fail and says "That's a miss".
If you select page 2 of python tag and then move to bounties then it loads the 2nd page of bounties.

[image: page issue]